# Type or namespace IUIWindowSceneDelegate, UIScene, UISceneSession, UISceneConnectionOptions could not be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building xamarin.ios application but sometimes I get this `The type or namespace name 'UISceneSession' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. There is no viable option in potential fixes, only generate classes. I tried restoring packages, removed packages and added back, restarted visual studio mac. I know that I am missing a reference but the problem is it does not always happen, sometimes it works sometimes it throws this message, I don't know if I am missing a reference or there is something else. Below you can see my references and what classes cannot be found.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Visual Studio > Check for Updates.. > download if there is packages need to be updated and restart Visual Studio

[image]